# Error retrieving field

Tags: java, hibernate, web-applications, jasper-reports

I have a problem with JasperReports. When attempting to download data from the database, I get this error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : mybean
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:821)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:785)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1482)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:126)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:864)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:540)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'mybean' on class 'class com.mg.shared.ABC'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1322)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:770)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:846)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
    ... 31 more
```

The problem is weird for me, becasue mybean is in ABC. What is more, my class 
ABC gets some data form other class DEF, and mybean is getting from DEF. When I am trying to display mybean from ABC, I recive the above error, but if I get mybean from DEF everything is ok.

Comment: from error it seems that your ABC class doesn't have property with name 'mybean'

Comment: Yes, I know, but ABC has this property. As I mentioned ABC gets mybean from DEF: DEF def; mybean = def.getBean();

Comment: may this can help you in fixing your problem: http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=54734

Comment: Can you post your bean definitions please?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is caused by your fields starting with a capital letter:

```
private String AdresDysponenta;
```

should be

```
private String adresDysponenta;
```

with a small a. The names of the getters and setters should remain the same.

This comes from the fact that Jasper uses Apache Commons Beanutils (PropertyUtils specifically), which doesn't like the fact that you're using an instance field with starts with a capital letter.

The general convention is that field names start with a small letter, but in the getter/setter it is a capital:

```
private int foo;

public int getFoo() {
  return foo;
}

public void setFoo(int foo) {
  this.foo = foo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

my field name is aBC, it hit the same error. just rename the variable into abc then you can export jasper report

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. It turned out that one of the files I called fields capitalized. Jasper could not cope with this.